# Preg_replace range character class

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

It is saying this and I wonder why that happened. It didn't happen before.

Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 16 in messenger.php on line 158

```
$pattern = array(
             "/[^@\s]*@[^@\s]*\.[^@\s]*/",
            "/[a-zA-Z]*[:\/\/]*[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+/i",
            '/\+?[0-9][0-9()-\s+]{4,20}[0-9]/'
        );
        $replacement    = array(
            "[removed email]",
            "[removed url]",
            "[removed phone]"
        );
        $message_text   = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $message_text);
```

Line 158 is the last one with $message_text.

Who can help?

Comment: Unescaped `-` in the last regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've forgotten to escape the dash in:

```
'/\+?[0-9][0-9()-\s+]{4,20}[0-9]/'
//       here __^
```

should be:

```
'/\+?[0-9][0-9()\-\s+]{4,20}[0-9]/'
```

Answer (score 1):

In `\+?[0-9][0-9()-\s+]{4,20}[0-9]`, you misplaced the hyphen and the regex engine thinks you are trying to build a range between `)` and `\s`.

It is not possible for a shorthand class to appear at the range boundary.

Here is an error appearing in Debuggex.com:

[image]

And here is an excerpt from the [PCRE Reference](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> An error is generated if a POSIX character  class  (see  below)  or  **an
>          escape  sequence other than one that defines a single character appears
>          at a point where a range ending character  is  expected**.  For  example,
>          `[z-\xff]` is valid, but `[A-\d]` and `[A-[:digit:]]` are not.

Use `\+?[0-9][0-9()\s+-]{4,20}[0-9]`, or escape the hyphen like `\+?[0-9][0-9()\-\s+]{4,20}[0-9]`.

See [working regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xT9nD1/1)